# Combination of breakpoint and irb (REPL)

Tags: ruby, debugging, irb, read-eval-print-loop, pry

Sometimes I want to experiment using IRB with some objects, but it's might be not that easy to reproduce the state and context that I need. Consider you want to play with syntax of an expression inside RSPec. So I want to implement something like this:

1. inside of code of an ruby application that I currently developing I invoke function `eval_server`
2. it creates server socket and listens for connections
3. I start some tool similar to IRB (let's call it `eval_client` - it should be implemented)
4. it creates client socket and connects to `eval_server`
5. I type some ruby expression in `eval_client`
6. `eval_client` sends it to `eval_server`
7. `eval_server` evaluates the expression in context of the object where it was invoked, serializes the result or exception (using `.inspect` for example), and sends it back to `eval_client`
8. `eval_client` displays the result

...

The **question** is:  if there similar tool already implemented? If not, are there some gems that might help me to implement it?

I know it might look like debugger. But I would prefer not to start rails server with debugger. I just want to add one like in code and have IRB in context of that line at next request.

**update:**

so according to the answer:

`eval_client` = `pry-remote`

`eval_server` = `binding.remote_pry`

https://github.com/mon-ouie/pry-remote

Comment: I heard about pry the other day but haven't had a chance to use it myself: https://github.com/pry/pry

Comment: lain, i'm not sure it's what i was looking for. but it might be really cool tool. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Pry](http://pry.github.com) plugin called pry-remote can do this:

see: https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Remote-sessions